# Is it possible to treat the time dimension as the rate of change of an extra spatial dimension?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein

In Minkowski Spacetime metric the time dimension is multiplied with $c$. This would allow us to swap it against a fourth space dimension: $cdt=dx_4$. One interpretation would be that the rate of change in this fourth space dimension is the observed time. In other words it looks like you can treat the fourth dimension as a representative for both space and time. Is this really possible?

As an example, consider a one dimensional wave, which can be described by two dimensions, viewed by an observer in different states . In both cases below the absolute speed is the speed of light c. The difference is that in Case A the wave is moving in both x (horizontal) and y (vertical) direction, while in Case B it is just moving in the x direction.

$c^2=v_x^2+v_y^2$

**Case A** 0: $\wedge$       1: $-$       2: $\vee$       3: $-$      4: $\wedge$

**Case B** 0: $\wedge$       1: $\wedge$       2: $\wedge$

The timeperiod T according to an observer for the wave in Case A to go from state 0 to state 4, or complete one oscillation and get back to the original state, would be decscibed by the distance s divided by c.

$T=s/c$

-> $cdT=ds$

The path of the wave could be descibed by Pythagoras

$ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$

The proper time period t would just be the distance in the y direction, simply moving up and down.

$dy=cdt$

Combining it all and we would get

$c^2*dT^2=dx^2+c^2*dt^2$

Reshuffle to express proper time as a function of observed time + space components

-> $-c^2*dt^2=dx^2-c^2*dT^2$

Now we have the produced the metric (-,+). Add two more space dimensions and you get (-,+,+,+). But we clearly started with two space dimensions and it is obviuos that we can use it mathimatically like taking the derivative of y with repect to x for example.

Now take a big jump to Kaluza-Klein theory. Using the logic from above, it means that we dont have to add a fifth dimension to get a fourth spatial dimension but rather we already have it if we decide to treat the time dimension as a spatial one. Working out the geometry of the fourth dimension with respect to the other three and you'll get electromagnetism without the extra scalar field (obs, this in an unsupported claim). Switching it back to the time view and you arrive back to standard General Relativity.

Comment: Rate of change with respect to what?

Answer (score 2):

The thing which ultimately distinguishes a temporal dimension from a spatial one is not the choice of units (which are arbitrary) but rather the *sign* of the corresponding term in the metric.  In Minkowski spacetime and cartesian coordinates, one has that
$$\mathrm ds^2 = \color{red}{-} c^2\mathrm dt^2 + \mathrm dx^2 + \mathrm dy^2 + \mathrm dz^2$$
In the coordinate system $(t,x,y,z)$, the first coordinate has dimensions of time while the others have dimensions of length; the metric components are $g_{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{diag}(-c^2,1,1,1)$ which makes the spacetime interval $\mathrm ds^2$ have dimensions of length. On the other hand, we could choose coordinates $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)\equiv (ct,x,y,z)$, in which case all of the coordinates have dimensions of length and the metric components are $g_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$.  Either choice is perfectly fine; the important thing is the minus sign before the first term in $\mathrm ds^2$.

I'm afraid I don't quite understand your point about Kaluza-Klein.  The idea of that theory is to add an additional *compact* dimension; under certain conditions, the extra degrees of freedom essentially behave like the electromagnetic 4-potential, suggesting that one might be able to understand electromagnetism as a manifestation of a compact extra dimension in addition to the "large" dimensions we readily observe.  This idea is very nice, but it does not match what we know from experiment (e.g. it predicts a concrete relationship between the mass and charge of a body).  In any case, there is no sense in which "reinterpreting" $ct$ as a spatial coordinate has any correspondence with Kaluza-Klein.

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation).